# Realisations of i.i.d. random variables with a density are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to use the fact that for i.i.d. random variables with a density $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ the set of outcomes $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ with probability 1, meaning that with probability 1 no linear combination with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ can be $0$ apart from the one with all coefficients equal to $0$.

This seems intuitively true and I see it being used in some articles, but I don't know and cannot find why exactly it is true. Does anyone have a compelling argument or a proof that I can use for this fact, or refer me to some literature?

Comment: I may be wrong but if it wasn't true then one of the $X_i $ could be written as a linear combination of the others and so they wouldn't be independent identical distributions.

Comment: A given linear combination with integer coefficients is zero with probability zero if the coefficients are not all zero. There are countable many such linear combinations hence, with full probability, they are simultaneously all nonzero, QED. (Only independence and the absence of atoms are relevant, having the same distribution is unneeded.)

Comment: @Karl For e.g. two iid non-degenerate Bernouilli-distributed rvs $X,Y$ it is not true, but $X$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving it for $n=1$ is the same as proving that $P\left(X_{1}=0\right)=0$.

To prove it for $n=2$ let $D:=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\mid x,y\text{ linearly dependent}\right\} $ and $D_y:=\{x\mid(x,y)\in D\}$.

$P\left(\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)\in D\right)=\int\int1_{D}\left(x,y\right)dF_{X_2}\left(x\right)dF_{X_1}\left(y\right)=\int P\left(X_{2}\in D_{y}\right)dF_{X_1}\left(y\right)$.

If $y\neq0$ then $D_{y}=\left\{ yq\mid q\in\mathbb{Q}\right\} $
wich is a countable set. Combining this with the fact that the distribution has a density we find $P\left(X_{2}\in D_{y}\right)=0$ for every $y\neq0$, and together with $P\left(X_{1}=0\right)=0$ this leads to $P\left(\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)\in D\right)=0$.

Now use induction to prove it for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\int \Pr (X_1 \in D_y)\ \mathrm{d} F(y)$?

Comment: You can choose the order of integration. I edited to make clear which order I have chosen.